# TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable in PySpark

Tags: java, pyspark

version details:

```
Python 3.10.9
PySpark  version 3.2.4
Java version "1.8.0_202"
```

I have been getting an error when executing PySpark.

```
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable in PySpark
```

code:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
sc = SparkContext()

inputWords = ["c", "c++", "java", ".net", "python", "sql", "angular","react","azure"]

wordRdd = sc.parallelize(inputWords)
words = wordRdd.take(3)   #Errors on this line
```

Any help is much appreciated!
I tried setting JAVA_HOME in environment variables. While the error did not go away.